# Filtering Results with JOIN

Tags: mysql, join

I have page called **questions** where the user gets asked questions and he/she has the option to answer them. The questions are pulled from a table called **questions**. When a question gets answered, a table in my database called **answered_questions** registers the id of the question answered and the id of the user who answered the question. The purpose of this is to hide the answered questions when the user accesses the page again.

On page load I'm trying to join the two tables and see if the **question_id** exists in both tables where the **userID** is that of the logged in user. If the id does exist in both tables then it shouldnt display the result per the use of **<>**. *Problem* is that its looping several times for each iteration when I try the following query:

```
SELECT questions.question_id, questions.user_id
FROM `questions`
JOIN `answered_questions`
ON questions.question_id <> answered_questions.question_id
WHERE answered_questions.user_id = ".$userID."
```

But it works fine when I use this

```
SELECT questions.question_id, questions.user_id
FROM `questions`
JOIN `answered_questions`
ON questions.question_id **=** answered_questions.question_id
WHERE answered_questions.user_id = ".$userID."
```

I sense that I'm doing something wrong with the logic of it all. Any help or clues would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get unanswered questions You can use [LEFT JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html):

```
SELECT questions.question_id, questions.user_id
FROM questions
LEFT JOIN answered_questions
  ON answered_questions.question_id = questions.question_id
  AND answered_questions.user_id = ".$userID."
WHERE answered_questions.question_id IS NULL
```